# sinatra-cors not responding with 200 when using middleware

Tags: ruby, jwt, sinatra, rack

I am writing a little app for my own curiosity, and am having trouble with the sinatra-cors gem not responding with a 200. This causes Chrome to fail the options request (and subsequently not completing the things on the page).

I have the following set in both a `Private` Controller, and a `Public` controller. The `Public` controller handles routes that require no authentication (such as login), and the `Private` controller handles routes that require authentication via JWT.

In the `Public` controller, I have :

```
    enable :cross_origin
  end

  before do
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  end

  # routes...
  options '*' do
    response.headers['Allow'] = 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Cache-Control, Accept'
    response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    200
  end
```

The `paths` in the `Public` controller correctly return 200 for its options requests, since CORS is set to allow all domains.
The `paths` in the `Private` controller fail with a 500, even though the same cors config is specified in the controller.

The difference, is that the `Private` controller, has a `use JwtAuth` statement at the start of the controller, which is the `middleware` that I have defined for using `JWT` tokens. When I remove this, the controllers pass the options request successfully.

The `JWT middleware` is as follows :

```
require 'json'
require 'jwt'

class JwtAuth
  CONTENT_TYPE = { 'Content-Type' => 'text/plain' }.freeze

  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  # rubocop:disable Metrics/MethodLength
  def call(env)
    options = { algorithm: 'HS256', iss: 'Jade-Liberty-Backend' }
    bearer = env.fetch('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', '').slice(7..-1)
    payload, _header = JWT.decode(bearer, 'thereisnospoon', true, options)

    env[:scopes] = payload['scopes']
    env[:user] = payload['user']

    @app.call env
  rescue JWT::DecodeError
    [401, CONTENT_TYPE, [Errors::INVALID_TOKEN]]
  rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature
    [403, CONTENT_TYPE, [Errors::TOKEN_EXPIRED]]
  rescue JWT::InvalidIssuerError
    [403, CONTENT_TYPE, [Errors::INVALID_ISSUER]]
  rescue JWT::InvalidIatError
    [403, CONTENT_TYPE, [Errors::INVALID_ISSUED_AT]]
  rescue e
    [500, CONTENT_TYPE, [Errors::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR]]
  end
  # rubocop:enable Metrics/MethodLength
end
```

I followed the following to create the middleware: https://auth0.com/blog/ruby-authentication-secure-rack-apps-with-jwt/

I am unsure why adding the middleware causes the options request to fail.

Comment: rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature must come before rescue JWT::DecodeError or expired tokens will be caught by JWT::DecodeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to an error in my middleware (Error module was not included in the source, and the default configuration of Rack caused errors not to be displayed)